# Apache Mahout - Read preference value from String

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm in a situation where I have a dataset that consists of the classical UserID, ItemID and preference values, however they are all strings.

I have managed to read the UserID and ItemID strings by Overriding the readItemIDFromString() and readUserIDFromString() methods in the FileDataModel class (which is a part of the Mahout library) however, there doesnt seem to be any support for the conversion of preference values if I am not mistaken.

If anyone has some input to what an approach to this problem could be I would greatly appreciate it.

To illustrate what I mean, here is an example of my UserID string "Conversion":

```
@Override
protected long readUserIDFromString(String value) {

    if (memIdMigtr == null) {
        memIdMigtr = new ItemMemIDMigrator();
    }

    long retValue = memIdMigtr.toLongID(value);
    if (null == memIdMigtr.toStringID(retValue)) {
        try {
            memIdMigtr.singleInit(value);
        } catch (TasteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}

String getUserIDAsString(long userId) {
    return memIdMigtr.toStringID(userId);
}
```

And the implementation of the AbstractIDMigrator:

```
public class ItemMemIDMigrator extends AbstractIDMigrator {

private FastByIDMap<String> longToString;

public ItemMemIDMigrator() {
    this.longToString = new FastByIDMap<String>(10000);
}

public void storeMapping(long longID, String stringID) {
    longToString.put(longID, stringID);
}

public void singleInit(String stringID) throws TasteException {
    storeMapping(toLongID(stringID), stringID);
}

public String toStringID(long longID) {
    return longToString.get(longID);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mahout is deprecating the old recommenders based on Hadoop. We have a much more modern offering based on a new algorithm called Correlated Cross-Occurrence (CCO). Its is built using Spark for 10x greater speed and gives real-time query results when combined with a query server.

This method ingests strings for user-id and item-id and produces results with the same ids so you don't need to manage those anymore. You really should have look at the new system, not sure how long the old one will be supported.

Mahout docs here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/recommender-overview.html and here: http://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html

The entire system described, with SDK, input storage, training of model and real-time queries is part of the Apache PredictionIO project and docs for the PIO and "Universal Recommender" and here: http://predictionio.incubator.apache.org/ and here: http://actionml.com/docs/ur

Comment: Oh how awesome! Thank you for letting me know, will definitely check it out. Too bad my teacher told the class to fix this part in particular untill the next session haha!

Comment: What we do in the new code is keep a BiMap (a thing in Guava) that acts as a bi-directional hashmap of string->int and int->string mappings. This allows you to keep in-memory hashmaps to translate Mahout int row and column ordinals (the ids you get from the recommender) into the original strings. The BiMap grows in proportion to the number of ids, not the amount of data and lookup is O(log(n)) too so scales well.

Comment: That sounds like a very smart idea, I'm asuming that counts for preference values as well?

Comment: Incoming datum are (user-id, event, item-id) these are considered "preference" indicators, The UR uses data of many types but the old Mahout recommenders and most recommenders use only conversion data--purchase in the E-Commerce case.  The BiMaps must be one for user-id to Mahout ordinal int and one for item-id to/from Mahout ordinal int.